# Select all entries from one table which has two specific entries in another table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

So, I have 2 tables defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tblPersons (
    id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE tblHobbies (
    person_id INTEGER REFERENCES tblPersons (id),
    hobby     TEXT
);
```

And for example I have 3 person added to **tblPersons**:

```
1 | John
2 | Bob
3 | Eve
```

And next hobbies in **tblHobbies**:

```
1 | skiing
1 | serfing
1 | hiking
1 | gunsmithing
1 | driving
2 | table tennis
2 | driving
2 | hiking
3 | reading
3 | scuba diving
```

And what I need, is query which will return me a list of person who have several specific hobbies.

The only thing I could've come up with, is this:

```
SELECT id, name FROM tblPersons
    INNER JOIN tblHobbies as hobby1 ON hobby1.hobby = 'driving'
    INNER JOIN tblHobbies as hobby2 ON hobby2.hobby = 'hiking'
    WHERE tblPersons.id = hobby1.person_id and tblPersons.id = hobby2.person_id;
```

But it is rather slow. Isn't there any better solution?

Comment: It would be way better to have three tables: persons, hobbies, and person_hobbies. So you would have each hobby once in the hobbies table and would be save from typos (e.g. serfing/surfing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't have a Primary Key on `tblHobbies` this is one cause of slow query (and other problems). Also you should consider creating a index on `tblHobbies.hobby`.

Second, I'd to advice you to create a third table to evidence N:N cardinality that exists in your model and avoid redundant hobbies. Something like:

```
--Person
CREATE TABLE tblPersons (
    id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT
);

--Hobby
CREATE TABLE tblHobbies (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    hobby TEXT
);

--Associative table between Person and Hobby
CREATE TABLE tblPersonsHobbies (
    person_id INTEGER REFERENCES tblPersons (id),
    hobby_id INTEGER REFERENCES tblHobbies (id),
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id, hobby_id)
);
```

Adds an extra table but it's worth it.

```
--Query on your current model
SELECT id, name FROM tblPersons
    INNER JOIN tblHobbies as hobby1 ON  tblPersons.id = hobby1.person_id
    WHERE hobby1.hobby IN ('driving', 'hiking');

--Query on suggested model
SELECT id, name FROM tblPersons
    INNER JOIN tblPersonsHobbies as personsHobby ON  tblPersons.id = personsHobby.person_id
    INNER JOIN tblHobbies as hobby1 ON hobby1.id = personsHobby.hobby_id
        WHERE hobby1.hobby IN ('driving', 'hiking');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that query on suggested module didn't work out for me, as it shows me even a person which has one of hobbies.

Comment: @externum Ah, ok. I missed this part. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Also creating an index really helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate the hobbies table to get persons with both hobbies:

```
select person_id
from tblhobbies
group by person_id
having count(case when hobby = 'driving' then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when hobby = 'hiking' then 1 end) > 0
```

Or better with a `WHERE` clause restricting the records to read:

```
select person_id
from tblhobbies
where hobby in ('driving', 'hiking')
group by person_id
having count(distinct hobby) =2
```

(There should be a unique constraint on person + hobby in the table, though. Then you could remove the `DISTINCT`. And as I said in the comments section it should even be person_id + hobby_id with a separate hobbies table. EDIT: Oops, I should have read the other answer. Michal suggested this data model three hours ago already :-)

If you want the names, select from the persons table where you find the IDs in above query:

```
select id, name
from tblpersons
where id in
(
  select person_id
  from tblhobbies
  where hobby in ('driving', 'hiking')
  group by person_id
  having count(distinct hobby) =2
);
```

With the better data model you'd replace

```
  from tblhobbies
  where hobby in ('driving', 'hiking')
  group by person_id
  having count(distinct hobby) =2
```

with

```
  from tblpersonhobbies
  where hobby_id in (select id from tblhobbies where hobby in ('driving', 'hiking'))
  group by person_id
  having count(*) =2
```

Comment: 1-st query is actually slower (